# codeigniter languages per domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns, multilingual

I would like to run 2 domains on same codeigniter base and each should reflect 2 different languages. What I would like to have schematically

```
domain.fr/controller/method should point to french content
domain.org/controller/method should point to english content
```

What is the best workaround to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like do a route re-write and redirect them to different content OR set a variable:

**Example:**

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain.fr':  $route['default_controller'] = "french"; break;
    case 'domain.org': $route['default_controller'] = "spanish"; break;
    default: $route['default_controller'] = "english"; break;
}
```

My example illustrates with **controllers** but you can set the

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

to something else (override the `config.php`)

Comment: thanks for feedback I will play a bit to see which would pass

Comment: Any success on this approach? How do you point the additional domain the main domain where the files are hosted?